# Problem with stage + rviz (segmentation fault)

Tags: simulation, rviz, ogre, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm simulating an array of robots with laser and I want to see all laser scans in Rviz.

After start roscore, if I rosrun stageros node and then rviz node, the problem appears:

```
gustavo@gustavo-ProBook:~$ rosrun rviz rviz 
[ INFO] [1361665790.163219703]: rviz version 1.9.20
[ INFO] [1361665790.163372795]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ WARN] [1361665794.846113178, 38.500000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/box.geom invalid valueCannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/box.geom invalid value in GLSLProgram::compile at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLSL/src/OgreGLSLExtSupport.cpp (line 65)
[ WARN] [1361665794.858389102, 38.500000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1425)
[ WARN] [1361665794.865810096, 38.500000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1425)
[ WARN] [1361665794.866371060, 38.500000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1425)
[ WARN] [1361665795.010072435, 38.600000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/pass_pos_color.vert Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/pass_pos_color.vert 0:1(15): preprocessor error: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting NEWLINE
 in GLSLProgram::compile at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLSL/src/OgreGLSLExtSupport.cpp (line 65)
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

The curious part is that if I rosrun rviz node first and then start stageros node, everything is fine.

So, where can I report this bug? Any solution?

**EDIT:**
I'm using ROS groovy, Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56104/problem-with-stage-+-rviz-(segmentation-fault)/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-03-26**:
I have the same problem with you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! This bug is not present in the lastest version of Rviz (1.9.24), I have to install it from github and it runs fine.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can report issues related to stage at [rtv/Stage](https://github.com/rtv/Stage/issues).

I'd also suggest running stageros with gdb to get more information about the segfault.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-02-24**:
Thanks for your answer! Actually the segfault appears running rviz node.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-24**:
In that case run rviz under gdb, and report the bug here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues